# How to set the preferred authentication method as password for DefaultSftpSessionFactory session?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Looking for a way to set the preferred authentication method to password. I am using Spring Integration 6.1.0 with Spring Boot 3.1.0.

in previous versions we could have done something like -

```
@Bean
Properties configProperties(){
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.setProperty("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
    return config;
}

@Bean
SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory(){
    System.out.println("Creating Session");
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost("someSFTPServer");
    factory.setUser("user");
    factory.setPassword("SomePassword");
    factory.setPort(22);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    **factory.setSessionConfig(configProperties());**
    return new CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>(factory);
}
```

but in 6.1.0 setSessionConfig() is not available.

Can someone please give some directions on how to proceed in this case ?

**Quick Background**

I am trying to connect to a SFTP Host using username and password and the connection is failing. Looking at the logs it appears that it attempts with method=keyboard-interactive for a long time and finally the host machine closes the connection after 2 mins. So, I am thinking if I can use method=password at the very beginning the connection might get established successfully.

I am able to connect to the same Host using Filezilla/Cyberduck using the same credentials without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of Spring Integration uses Apache MINA project to connect to SFTP via its SSH client.

See its respective option which is out of Spring Integration scope:

```
@Override
public void setUserAuthFactories(List<UserAuthFactory> userAuthFactories) {
```

where you can choose just only `UserAuthPasswordFactory` for your consideration.

See respective ctor to inject a custom `SshClient`:

```
/**
 * Instantiate based on the provided {@link SshClient}, e.g. some extension for HTTP/SOCKS.
 * @param sshClient the {@link SshClient} instance.
 * @param isSharedSession true if the session is to be shared.
 */
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory(SshClient sshClient, boolean isSharedSession) {
```

Comment: Artem Bilan - Thanks for your response. Can you please suggest how can I use setUserAuthFactories() to keep only the UserAuthPasswordFactory for the custom SshClient ?

Comment: injecting a custom SshClient looks to be not very straight forward as lots of additional configurations needs to be done before it can be passed to DefaultSftpSessionFactory. :(

Comment: See `DefaultSftpSessionFactory.doInitInnerClient()` to borrows ideas how Spring Integration initializes that `SshClient`. We don't have any hooks for the `setUserAuthFactories()` and that is really out of Spring Integration project scope. Please, consult with Apache MINA community.